# file-link on Intranetpage in IE 9 and IE 10 should open Windows Explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I want to open the windows explorer out of IE 9/10 with a link like:

```
<a href="file:///c:/temp">c:\temp</a>
```

If I open the index.html from FileSystem directly with IE it works. 
If I open it from IIS-Host, I don't get an error and IE doesn't open the Windows Explorer.

Is there any possibility to get it work with IE-Options for the Intranetpage?

Thanks in advance!
Normen

Comment: Relevant? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/114515

Comment: I have added the site to the "Local Intranet" Sites in IE-Options: Same result. IE does not open the windows explorer.